# How to create Insert script using c#

Tags: c#, mysql

From my c# code behind, i pass a query to mysql database and get the data in a DataTable.
Now i want to use the data in data table to write the Insert query in a script file [.sql]

The objective of doing so is, whatever records i select from mysql, i should write that to a script file as backup. Thais why i need the insert statements.

How ? Or any other idea is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question... in MySQL, those INSERT statements would be like any other insert into that table, except that you will want to include the identity column and its value if there is one.

Comment: so are you trying to generate a "backup script" for the data in the table?

Comment: @Axarydax, YES i want to take the backup and write to a script file.

Comment: then look at the answer provided by @eric eijkelenboom, it's exactly what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't that why they invented [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)?

This allows you to dump a table to as file, as a create statement + a bunch of insert statements.

EDIT: see also this article about [Using mysqldump](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=174365&seqNum=4)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're doing something like this

```
string sql = "INSERT sometable (a, b, c) SELECT 1, 2, 3";
DataLayer.Run( sql );
```

and you want to do something like this

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText( "script.sql", sql );
```

Or, to log multiple statements,

```
System.IO.File.AppendAllText( "script.sql", sql + Environment.NewLine );
```